# Query to output content of AllXml column of ELMAH_Error sql server table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, elmah

I am having trouble writing query so that I can query the content of AllXml column inside Elmah_Error table.

How can I list out all the item nodes as an output of the query. 
How could I write query to only list for certain item nodes?

I would like to get follow resultset:

item                value

=====               =====

ALL_HTTP              HTTP_CONNECTION:xxxx

ALL_RAW               Connection: xxxxx

I would also like to be able to filter the query by ErrorID

Content of AllXml column may look like this.

```
<error
  application="/"
  message="hello world"
  source="TestWebElmah"
  detail="xxxxx">
  <serverVariables>
    <item
      name="ALL_HTTP">
      <value
        string="HTTP_CONNECTION:xxxx" />
    </item>
    <item
      name="ALL_RAW">
      <value
        string="Connection: xxxxx" />
    </item>

  </serverVariables>
</error>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remote Addr nodes

```
select T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as REMOTE_ADDR
from 
(select cast(AllXml as xml) as AllXml from ELMAH_Error) e
   cross apply AllXml.nodes('//item[@name="REMOTE_ADDR"]') as T(N)
```

HTTP User Agents which contain *mozilla*

```
select T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as HTTP_USER_AGENT
from 
(select cast(AllXml as xml) as AllXml from ELMAH_Error) e
   cross apply AllXml.nodes('//item[@name="HTTP_USER_AGENT"]') as T(N)
where T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') like '%mozilla%'
```

[Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) table stores the AllXml column as nvarchar so it needs to be casted to xml

all tags + values, by error id

```
select T.N.value('@name', 'varchar(30)') as Name,
       T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Value
from 
(select cast(AllXml as xml) as AllXml from ELMAH_Error where ErrorId = 'DC82172B-F2C0-48CE-8621-A60B702ECF93') e
cross apply AllXml.nodes('/error/serverVariables/item') as T(N)
```

*Before voting down this answer, because uses most of the part of Mikael Eriksson's answer, I let you know I'll happily accept the downvotes only for this reason, since is mainly true*

Comment: How can I get list of all the item and values in AllXml column?

Comment: see my update. I removed the top 10 clause also, because I have a huge elmah table and takes a while to test it..

Comment: thanks Adrian... How could I filter by specific error in Elmah table.. ie ErrorID?...

Comment: welcome, by Id is easy, even is a GUID, you can place the guid like any other string

Comment: I would like to filter the 'all tags + values' result by ErrorID.. Please let me know.. and thank you for all your help

Comment: +1 from me. A good nights sleep got in the way of updating my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you all `item` nodes

```
select T.N.value('@name', 'varchar(30)') as Name,
       T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Value
from Elmah_Error
  cross apply AllXml.nodes('/error/serverVariables/item') as T(N)
```

If you want to filter on any of the values you can put that in a sub-query apply a regular where clause.

```
select Name, 
       Value
from
  (
    select T.N.value('@name', 'varchar(30)') as Name,
           T.N.value('(value/@string)[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Value
    from Elmah_Error
      cross apply AllXml.nodes('/error/serverVariables/item') as T(N)
  ) T
where Name = 'ALL_HTTP'
```

Comment: the only problem with Elmah table is that the AllXml column is not of xml type, so it needs a cast

Comment: Mikael, when I run your queries, I get the following error... The XMLDT method 'nodes' can only be invoked on columns of type xml.  I noticed that AllXml column is of type ntext. Please assist me.. thanks

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner, you need to cast it to xml probably Mikael Eriksson will show you how

Comment: I am trying but no luck so far.

Comment: @dotnet-practitioner - Timezone issues and a good nights sleep got in the way of updating the answer with the `cast` from `varchar`. But I see that you have it resolved now.